# How to search a pdf after opening it from a new intent?

Tags: android

I've used the code from the PDF rendering question

[How to render PDF in Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2883355/how-to-render-pdf-in-android)

And it works! Props to the answerer, but my question is about doing that same thing but also sending a keyword to search in the pdf. I have no idea how to do this, should I set a flag? Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You need to contact the authors of every PDF viewer written for Android, and ask them.

Comment: The PDF viewer I'm talking about is "PDF viewer" by HTC default on the droid eris. I was wondering if there is anyway to open it to a specific page?

Comment: Since that is not open source and is not documented, I doubt anybody outside of a few HTC engineers will know, and they ain't talkin'.