# How to view pdf in android browser?

Tags: android, android-pdf-api, androidpdfviewer

friends,

any one guide me how can i view pdf file in android browser?

or any other useful way?

any help would be appreciated.

Comment: This question, having nothing to do with programming, is best asked on ForceClose.com. That being said, Adobe does have a PDF viewer application on the Market, and there are various third party ones as well.

Comment: i am talking about programmatically man..

Comment: in my own application if i have pdf files then i want to open them got idea?? it is programming question.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to render PDF in Android](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2883355/how-to-render-pdf-in-android)

Comment: try http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4468621/android-load-pdf-pdf-viewer/4525717#4525717

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
File file = new File("filename");
intent.setDataAndType(Uri.fromFile(file), "application/pdf");
startActivity(intent);
```