# Android - Load PDF / PDF Viewer

Tags: android, pdf

I want to display pdf contents on webview.

Here is my code:

```
WebView webview = new WebView(this); 
setContentView(webview); 
webview.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true); 
webview.loadUrl("URL/Demo_PDF.pdf");
```

### Problem:

When i am trying to run the application, at that time I am getting blank screen.

And also, if there is any PDF viewer then also suggest me !!

FYI, I have already set internet permission.

Comment: For all, **This question is too old now, at that time PDF Viewer/Reader were not available so i did with this solution**

Answer (score 50, accepted):

Finally, i got a solution, actually i made a trick to load a pdf file using Google Docs inside a webview:

```
webview.loadUrl("http://docs.google.com/gview?embedded=true&url=http://myurl.com/demo.pdf");
```

Comment: In my case it fails because "Your browser must support Javascript" although I enable Javascript in my Android browser.

Comment: @anticafe have you used setJAvascriptenabled(true) inside code ?

Comment: oh I see. By default Android webview disables Javascript. So every times create a webview, we must setJAvascriptenabled(true).

Comment: @anticafe ya it is, you have to.

Comment: @Paresh "Disadvantage:network connection". Anyhow the pdf is also located on a server, so network connection is a must even if you were not reading the pdf using a webview.. so this way i can use google gview to load pdf from web into a webview.. what if my pdf is on the sdcard.? any sugesstions/solutions.

Comment: @paresh : i am getting error : Sorry, we are unable to retrieve the document for viewing or you don't have permission to view the document. I have event opened the Url loaded in the my Desktop browser.  Do we need some authentication? I have also enabled javascript =true from code...

Comment: Why do you all post the same solution for this quetsion? This is NOT a solution for PDF offline reading.

Comment: @Emerald214 pls check the question date, at that time muPDF and other kind of API and library were not available.

Comment: @PareshMayani: when i use this url it redirect me to viewer term and condition page rather than opening PDF. Why?

Comment: @PareshMayani: Is there any robust solution to display pdf from sdcard in application itself ?

Comment: @MehulJoisar As I have mentioned in comment over the question, I had used this solution as there weren't any PDF library/framework available, but now there are many libraries/tools available (e.g. muPDF) by which you can view/read/edit PDF files into the android application. Give `muPDF` at least a try!

Comment: @PareshMayani: Yes, I am working on it on the other hand but I was looking for optional way because muPDF requires to build by NDK.

Comment: @MehulJoisar so what! Ultimately you are getting PDF reader in free :)

Comment: @PareshMayani: Yeah! that's true :)

Answer (score 10):

I'm sorry but WebView does not display PDF content.
What you might want is a PDF viewer that responds to the PDF MIME type.

Here are a couple of free open-source libraries you might want to check:

- [droidreader](http://code.google.com/p/droidreader/)
- [apv pdf reader](http://code.google.com/p/apv/)

Comment: then what about this MIME type: android:mimeType="application/pdf" ?

Comment: check [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2784847/how-do-i-determine-if-android-can-handle-pdf)

Answer (score 1):

WebView does not have a PDF plugin. You should store the PDF locally and open an intent for viewing that kind of content.

Comment: ya this idea i think it is helpful, but for what i need to open Intent ? i mean by which application i can use intent?

Answer (score 1):

You can try using mupdf (www.mupdf.com) 
You can build a native code library (libmupdf.so) to be loaded onto your android project using the ndk.
This would ensure a lot faster rendering of pdf files...
check out the project at : http://mupdf.com/repos/mupdf/android/

Comment: I was successful in building the library. (libmupdf.so)

Comment: i havent idea of NDK yet, so it is difficult me to implement such, can you pass the builded library to me??

Comment: As of now, the library that I have built generates png files for all the pages in a pdf & aslo stores the raw raster data onto the sdcard. As of rendering the pdf, as is onto a 'View' on Android, you'd need to refer the 'mupdf-android' project. I can share the library I've built, if required.

Comment: Roy, can you pass along the "libmupdf.so" library you built plz? sachin6670i@gmail.com

Comment: Sorry for the delay, It's quite a huge size, come's up to 7 MB. Besides, the interface I have developed is only used to export raster data... Let me know if I can be of help programmatically...