# can we render pdf on web view in android

Tags: android

can we render pdf and show it on web view in android. kindly help me out

Comment: WebView in Android cannot show PDFs. You should use any third party PDF reader like DroidReader or modify open source one.

Answer (score 5):

Yes you can load PDF in Webview using Google's gview, It is a trick.

Here you can have my solution for the same trick: [Android - Load PDF / PDF Viewer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4468621/android-load-pdf-pdf-viewer/4525717#4525717).

Answer (score 2):

You cant open PDF file directly in android web browser but using Google Docs Viewer. you can open it in android Browser like:

```
String webUrl="http://myweb.com/demo.pdf";
mWebView.loadUrl("https://docs.google.com/gview?embedded=true&url="+ webUrl);
```

Answer (score 0):

Unluckily, Google has changed the api... When you try to load the docs.google.com/gview url, the web view is redirect to the new drive.google.com/viewerng that can't render the pdf in the Android WebView...

Any other clever solution? :D