# How to move direct to a particular page number of apdf file when click on a button

Tags: android, android-layout, android-widget, android-manifest

I wrote code for displaying a pdf file in android application.
I want to display a particular page when click on a button. Please help me in this regards.

Thanks...

I created the class like this

```
package com.tiru;

import java.io.File;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import android.app.AlertDialog;
import android.app.ListActivity;
import android.content.ActivityNotFoundException;
import android.content.DialogInterface;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.graphics.PorterDuff;
import android.graphics.PorterDuffColorFilter;
import android.graphics.drawable.Drawable;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.view.Window;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.ImageButton;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class SetupForAirport extends ListActivity{

    private List<String> item = null;
    private List<String> path = null;
    private String root = "/";
    private TextView myPath;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_CUSTOM_TITLE);

        setContentView(R.layout.setup_airport);

        getWindow().setFeatureInt(Window.FEATURE_CUSTOM_TITLE,
                R.layout.window_title_for_setupairport);



        Button buttonDep = (Button) findViewById(R.id.setDep);
        buttonDep.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                //for Samsung tab
                myPath = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.path);
                getDir("/mnt/sdcard/external_sd/doc1/JEPPESEN MANUAL/");    

            }
        });

    }

    private void getDir(String dirPath) {
        myPath.setText("Location: " + dirPath);

        item = new ArrayList<String>();
        path = new ArrayList<String>();

        File f = new File(dirPath);
        File[] files = f.listFiles();

        if (!dirPath.equals(root)) {

            item.add(root);
            path.add(root);

            item.add("../");
            path.add(f.getParent());

        }

        for (int i = 0; i < files.length; i++) {
            File file = files[i];
            path.add(file.getPath());
            if (file.isDirectory())
                item.add(file.getName() + "/");
            else
                item.add(file.getName());
        }

        ArrayAdapter<String> fileList = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, 
                R.layout.row, item);
        setListAdapter(fileList);
    }

    protected void onListItemClick(ListView l, View v, int position, long id) {

        File file = new File(path.get(position));

        if (file.isDirectory()) {
            if (file.canRead())
                getDir(path.get(position));
            else {
                new AlertDialog.Builder(this)
                        .setIcon(R.drawable.icon)
                        .setTitle(
                                "[" + file.getName()
                                        + "] folder can't be read!")
                        .setPositiveButton("OK",
                                new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

                                    @Override
                                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog,
                                            int which) {
                                        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                                    }
                                }).show();
            }
        } else {

            //For Reading pdf file
            Uri path = Uri.fromFile(file);
            Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
            intent.setDataAndType(path, "application/pdf");
            intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);

            try {
                startActivity(intent);
            } catch (ActivityNotFoundException e) {
                Toast.makeText(SetupForAirport.this,
                        "No Application Available to View PDF",
                        Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }

        }
    }

}
```

I want, when click on buttonDep it will go to the page number 10 of the pdf file

Comment: Are you using a different application to open the PDF file ?

Comment: @2rk no , I am using in the same application and  my path is like this    /mnt/sdcard/external_sd/doc1/JEPPESEN MANUAL/x.pdf

Comment: You are using `Action` to filter the `Intent` and then you fire the intent. This seems to me like you are giving an option to the user to choose his preferable PDF reader. Am I right ?

Comment: Yes, more more clarification I am editing my code that I wrote

Comment: @2rk Please look my code, I posted now.

Comment: You can put extra information (like starting page #) with your intent using `intent.putExtra()` method. However If you are using other applications to read a pdf file and the application do NOT handle this extra info, then you can NOT do this.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it another way like:

```
     Button b;
     b = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button1);
      ed = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText1);
        ed.setText("http://static.googleusercontent.com/external_content/untrusted_dlcp/source.android.com/en//compatibility/2.1/android-2.1-cdd.pdf");


    b.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {
             String URL  = ed.getText().toString();
             URL.trim();
             System.out.println(URL);
             WebView web1 =(WebView)findViewById(R.id.webview);
             web1.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
             web1.loadUrl("http://docs.google.com/gview?embedded=true&url="+URL);    


        }
    });
```

Comment: I tried ur method, It works well for web. But I want to show the pdf file from the external sd card, and also want to display a particular page when click on the button. In that button , I have to set the path with the page number like  /mnt/sdcard/external_sd/doc1/JEPPESEN MANUAL/x.pdf#5

Comment: do you have display only one pdf or multiple?

Comment: if you want to do from "**/mnt/sdcard** " so just put as it as path to editable text box and run application.

Comment: I tried ur code, like the below    String path  = "/sdcard/doc1/JEPPESEN MANUAL/male.pdf";
  path.trim();
        System.out.println(path);
        WebView web1 =(WebView)findViewById(R.id.webview);
        web1.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        web1.loadUrl("http://docs.google.com/gview?embedded=true&url="+path);        But I m unable to see the pdf file.It showing the msg, "Unable to retrieve the document or u don't hv permission to view the document"

Comment: i foud that you have not view from locally it s only get from url.

Comment: may be, this is help to you : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4468621/android-load-pdf-pdf-viewer

Comment: I tried a lot for it, but same error.I can't find where the error.U tried using the sd card.Please look into my code

Comment: @scorpio let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/1205/discussion-between-tiru-and-scorpio)

Comment: sorry i cant able to jump to chat because firewall problem.

Comment: Is there no way to access locally using the webview ?

Comment: Hi Friend, for reading a specific pdf file I wrote the below code. File dir = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(); File file = new File(dir, "/mnt/sdcard/external_sd/doc1/JEPPESEN MANUAL/male.pdf"); Uri path = Uri.fromFile(file);  Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW); intent.setDataAndType(path, "application/pdf"); intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP); startActivity(intent); But showing invalid file path. Have u any idea, why it comes like...

Comment: just try to putting file in assets folder.

Comment: <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE">