# Download PDF from url and read it

Tags: android

```
public void openDocumentWithInstalledApp(String filename) {
String mimetype = "";
url = url+ filename;
if (!url.startsWith("http://") && !url.startsWith("https://")) {
url = "http://" + url;
}
Intent browserIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse(url));
startActivity(browserIntent);

/*what should I do?*/

mimetype = "application/pdf";
File file = new File("/mnt/sdcard/Download/" + filename);
Intent intent1 = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
intent1.setDataAndType(Uri.fromFile(file), mimetype);
intent1.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
startActivity(intent1);
}
```

First, I try to download a pdf from url.
Second, I try to read the pdf above download.
But it may not download finish.
If I want to wait the pdf download finish.
What should I do?

Comment: You can use threads to download data.This way you will know when its done.

Comment: Here is the solution: [Android - Load PDF / PDF Viewer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4468621/android-load-pdf-pdf-viewer)

Comment: How to use threads to download to confirm it finish?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As an alternative you can try opening pdf in google docs. Try below code-

```
   String pdfurl = "http://www.example.com/yourfile.pdf";
   String googleDocsUrl = "http://docs.google.com/viewer?url="+pdfurl;
   Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
   intent.setDataAndType(Uri.parse(googleDocsUrl ), "text/html");
   startActivity(intent);
```