# ActivityNotFoundException: No Activity found to handle Intent { act=android.intent.action.VIEW dat=file:///mnt/sdcard/testdata5.pdf

Tags: android, android-intent, android-activity

I have a requirement to display pdf file from SD card. This pdf file is created after a network operation. I'm getting `ActivityNotFoundException` when trying to open pdf through `activity.startActivity(intent);` . Below is code
**folder_list_details.xml**

```
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <RelativeLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent">
 <ListView 
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:id="@+id/listV_main"/>
<ImageView 
    android:id="@+id/photo"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:paddingRight="15dp"
    android:paddingTop="10dp" />
        <TextView android:id="@+id/name"
    android:textSize="14sp" 
    android:textStyle="bold" 
    android:textColor="#000000" 
    android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@id/photo"/>

      </RelativeLayout>
```

**FolderActivity.java**

```
    public class FolderListActivity extends ListActivity{

public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    Log.i("FolderListActivity", "onCreate" );
    FolderDisplay folderObj = new FolderDisplay(FolderListActivity.this);
    folderObj.execute((Void) null);
     }
    }
```

**FolderDisplay.java** :

```
     @Override
       protected void onPostExecute(Void v) {
    try{
                //activity is an  instance of FolderListActivity
        final ListView lv1 =activity.getListView(); 
        lv1.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
      public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View v, int position,long id) {                           
            File file =Utility.getInstance().getFile();
                Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
                 intent.setDataAndType(Uri.fromFile(file), "application/pdf");
                 intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
                  activity.startActivity(intent);
            }  
        });
    }catch(Exception e){
        }
 }
```

**Mainfest.xml**

```
                  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
             <manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
           package="com.example.testlogin"
           android:versionCode="1"
             android:versionName="1.0" >

      <uses-sdk
       android:minSdkVersion="11"
     android:targetSdkVersion="17" />
       <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
     <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE">
       </uses-  permission>

      <application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" 
    android:debuggable="true"
    >
    <activity
        android:name="com.example.testlogin.LoginActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize|stateVisible" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
      </activity>
        <activity
        android:name="com.example.testlogin.RepoListActivity"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_repo_list" >
       </activity>
       <activity
        android:name="com.example.testlogin.FolderListActivity"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_folder_list" >
      </activity>
     </application>

     </manifest>
```

**Error** I'm getting

```
android.content.ActivityNotFoundException: No Activity found to handle Intent { act=android.intent.action.VIEW dat=file:///mnt/sdcard/Alfdata/testdata5.pdf typ=application/pdf flg=0x4000000 }
```

Answer (score 2):

That is because your device or emulator does not have an application capable of viewing a local PDF file.

Comment: I'm getting the same error while opening text file as well. Any idea?

Comment: @Sam: That is because your device or emulator does not have an application capable of viewing a text file.

Comment: thanks for quick response! Can you please let me know what I need to do to resolve this issue?

Comment: @Sam: Install apps on your device that can view PDFs and/or text files.

Comment: Any suggestion what apps I need to install?

Comment: @Sam: You are welcome to browse [the Play Store](http://play.google.com) to find PDF viewers, text file viewers, etc. for your device. Most that advertise that they can view those types of files will support `ACTION_VIEW`.

Comment: I'll try and let you know, Thanks for your suggestion

Comment: Now, I'm able to view text file after changing code to - String extension = android.webkit.MimeTypeMap.getFileExtensionFromUrl(Uri.fromFile(file).toString());
           String mimetype = android.webkit.MimeTypeMap.getSingleton().getMimeTypeFromExtension(extension);
               intent.setDataAndType(Uri.fromFile(file), mimetype);  However, still I'm not able to open pdf and JPEG file

Comment: @CommonsWare am facing the same error when am trying to open udp video. With http its working fine. And am opening my video on real device only instead am facing error.Any idea?

Answer (score 0):

I faced the same problem apparently , Android does not have a stock PDF Viewer but as an alternative if you have the pdf up on the cloud then u can open it in a webView which opens up a google docs link pointing to your pdf url .

Look at this post [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4468621/android-load-pdf-pdf-viewer)

Comment: I'm getting the same error while opening text file as well. Any idea?

Answer (score 0):

Whenever you start an intent, you would have to have the native app installed on the emulator to handle that intent. Ex. If you invoke an intent with Maps as the action, you would have to use the Google API's based emulator. By default, android emulator does not have a PDF reader. You could test this on a device with a PDF reader and it should work fine.

Pls mark the answer as correct if you think your issue has been resolved.

Comment: Lokoko, could you please elaborate your answer, how do I achieve this?