# How to read a pdf in android

Tags: android

I want to read a PDF file in android.
I placed my PDF files in the assets folder.

How can i read the PDF file from there?

[PDF Reader Link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2883355/how-to-render-pdf-in-android/)

I have checked the above link but it does not work for me. 
It gives me an error saying that the Activity was not found.

And I also want to open a PDF file in WebView. So is it possible to read PDF in WebView?

Comment: why is it not working? what error do you get? paste the stacktrace and a relevant snippet of code, please.

Comment: I do not want to open application from another application. I want to read pdf file in webview.

Comment: Should be closed, not programming/development related. This question belongs on android.stackexchange.com

Comment: If it says Activity not found... have you listed your Activity in AndroidManifest.xml?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You need to have a application which can support that mimetype and open it.
In your device/emulator that app is not installed so it is throwing error

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply.
But if i want to open a PDF file through WebView, how can i read that PDF file.

Comment: You cant read a PDF file through WebView. Try it yourself, open the browser and google for a pdf. Try to open it... you will be prompted to download it and open it with another application...

Comment: Yes you are right. Another alternative i found out that convert pdf pages into png and display them in webview.

Answer (score 15):

u can download PDFbox API to read PDF in android 
try this link: http://pdfbox.apache.org/

Comment: As I understood PDFBox does not support the Android plattform due to references to awt and swing.

Answer (score 4):

Another great solution to read pdf using externally installed application like `Adobe Reader`.

```
private void openPDF(final String pathToPDF) {
    File file = new File(pathToPDF);
    Uri path = Uri.fromFile(file);
    Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
    intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
    intent.setDataAndType(path, "application/pdf");
    try {
        startActivity(intent);
    } catch (ActivityNotFoundException e) {
        Toast.makeText(this, "Application not found", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
}
```

Comment: I think Your code works fine. But will you please tell me what is that mRealPath ? I want the value of the mRealPath.

Comment: @iDroid mRealPath is the path of your Pdf file and "application_type" is applications.

Comment: @Azharahmed: Your device should have installed the "ThinkOffice".

Comment: if i want to make an seprate applicatioin for a PDF reader or viewer then which lib n how them i have to use....??

Comment: Does your snippet call an external application? If yes, it is not good solution. I am finding a snippet which really reads pdf directly.

Answer (score 0):

Google cached displays formats like pdf, ppt, docx, etc. And you don't need to install any application at all.
Search the link in google and go to Cached.

Answer (score 0):

```
 private void openPDF(final String path) {
        File file = new File(path);
        Uri uri;
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M) {
            uri = FileProvider.getUriForFile(context, context.getPackageName() + ".provider", file);
        } else {
            uri = Uri.fromFile(file);
        }

        Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
        intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
        intent.setDataAndType(path, "application/pdf");
        intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION);
        try {
            startActivity(intent);
        } catch (ActivityNotFoundException e) {
            Toast.makeText(this, "Application not found", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    }
```

Comment: Above code is working fine by using File provider which is added in Android Manifext and using android read and write permission as well as must be added <provider>android:grantUriPermissions="true" </provider>