# read PDF with tables and all

Tags: android

read PDF with structure not only text.. I had used PDFbox but it only extract texts???? huh.

Comment: What exactly do you want to do? Did you look at the other similar questions here, like http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3831019/how-to-read-a-pdf-in-android ?

Comment: How about trying the SDK from Adobe for reading PDFs?

Comment: is Adobe SDK is avail? open source