# Is it possible to read a pdf document with iText library in android

Tags: android

Some of the members says that the iText library is only for creating a PDF document,we cant read the PDF document using iText library.Is that true?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i think u can use itext library for reading also, but the problem is that u cant have tables & images or format of pdf pages i.e. only text can be read

Comment: is there anyother libraries available for reading the entire content of the PDF document...?

Comment: yes, Jpedal, mupdf,pdfbox & etc... go here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3831019/how-to-read-a-pdf-in-android/5090539#5090539

Comment: u can either go for pdfbox or Mupdf

Comment: i have decided to use Mupdf... could u please give me the guidance where can i download it and how to add it to my android project?

Comment: If you new where to get what you need, iText can get it for you. You'll have to do a lot of low-level pdf stuff in iText then.