# How to read PDF file with url in Android

Tags: java, android

My Code is :

```
File file = new File(docpath);
String mimetype = "application/pdf";

Uri path = Uri.fromFile(file);
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
intent.setDataAndType(path, mimetype);
intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);

startActivity(intent);
```

If I want to use the application/pdf method
What should I do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

PDFs are not naturally supported in android. You will need to use an open source library.

Android PDF Viewer, for example. 
http://code.google.com/p/apv/

Comment: May I use the installed Adobe PDF Reader or Quick Office App to view PDF file with url, but not download it.

Comment: PDFs are not supported in webviews, so you'll always have to download it from a URL. http://stackoverflow.com/a/3831066/902730
If the pdf isn't changing you can store it locally on your app. 

Supporting PDF reading functionality yourself removes external dependencies which could cause your app to crash. Quick Office and Adobe PDF reader are not google apps, so they are not guaranteed to be in the phone at runtime (unlike GoogleMaps, for example, which is always guaranteed to be there). If you try to run an external app from your app and it is not there then your app will crash.