# What PDF library should I use for Android?

Tags: java, android

I have been developing Android application, and I need to read PDF-files in my app. There are some requirements for lib:

- will the solution be able to read fairly large files? Like if the file is much larger than available memory, would it be able to read piece by piece as the user browses?
- will in the future this module be able to read from a stream not just from a file?
- will the solution, with this or future project/effort be able to re-flow text - to accommodate different screen sizes?
- what version of the PDF format (up to) will it be able to read.

Please, recommend me some library.

Comment: Check out this link. Hope you will get your answer[http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3831019/how-to-read-a-pdf-in-android][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3831019/how-to-read-a-pdf-in-android

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hi yeah you can do it with iText lib in java. see this [Itext Lib](http://www.qoppa.com/solutions/javapdf.html)
and also see this [Code](http://technotransit.wordpress.com/2011/06/17/using-itext-in-android/)

hope it will help you. and one thing you cant edit PDF in android directly yet there is no such API or lib. try to fin more Google it.