# How can i use notepad for textview?

Tags: android, textview, notepad

i'm very biginner so bare me please

I have two activity in my project

first is text1.xml

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context=".Text1" >

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="36dp"
        android:text="Button1" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button3"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/button2"
        android:layout_below="@+id/button2"
        android:layout_marginTop="82dp"
        android:text="Button3" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/button1"
        android:layout_below="@+id/button1"
        android:layout_marginTop="70dp"
        android:text="Button2" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

and second is text2.xml :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_marginRight="20dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="28dp"
        android:text="TextView" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

I want put 3 notepad in my project that when user press first button in text1.xml first notepad shown in textview in text2.xml and when user press second button in text1.xml second notepad shown in textview in text2.xml and 3rd notepad like 1st and 2nd too .....
how can i add text from notepad to textview ,,,, what is code  ??
where should i add my notepads in my project ? in assets ???

Comment: u can use same activity again and agian y r u creating many activity..

Comment: yes ... i have just to activity .... first is my buttons and second textview ...... how i can add text of notepad to textview ? what is code ????

Comment: i mean just read the data from whatever u want and just use setText method to set the text to textview

Comment: can i do this with pdf format or just txt ??

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3831019/how-to-read-a-pdf-in-android

Comment: settext(r.assets.txt) 
is it right ????

Comment: nope u hv to read the content first and then dumnp into textview

Comment: excuse me .... I'm very biginner 
how can i read the content ??? 
can u explain in more detail ??? 
thanks alot

Comment: if u wanna read the content of pdf read the link above i have pasted from there u will read the content and u can write to textview directly or store in txt file and then set text to textview

Answer (score 0):

you could place all notepad over each other using framelayout/relativelayout and toggle the visibility of particular layout using buttons.