# Does android have a built-in PDF viewer?

Tags: android, pdf, android-2.2-froyo, built-in

I heard something recently about it being included in Froyo and I was wondering if there was any truth to it. If there is, it would help me with an app idea greatly.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are probably referring to the [Adobe Reader](http://news.cnet.com/8301-27076_3-20005815-248.html), which is freely available for Android 2.1+. Some devices also have other applications pre-installed for rendering pdf files. See this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2883355/how-to-render-pdf-in-android/) on how you can open the default pdf viewer from your application.

Answer (score 1):

Android has a built in framework from Android 5.0 / Lollipop, it's called [PDFRenderer](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/pdf/PdfRenderer.html).

There's an official example on Google's developer site:

http://developer.android.com/samples/PdfRendererBasic/index.html