# Read pdf file from sd card

Tags: android

I want to read a pdf file stored in my sd card, I tried using this snippet

```
    File file = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()
            + "/vvveksperten" + "/ypc.pdf");

    PackageManager packageManager = getPackageManager();
    Intent testIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
    testIntent.setType("application/pdf");
    List list = packageManager.queryIntentActivities(testIntent,
            PackageManager.MATCH_DEFAULT_ONLY);
    Intent intent = new Intent();
    intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
    Uri uri = Uri.fromFile(file);
    intent.setDataAndType(uri, "application/pdf");
    startActivity(intent);
```

but it gave me an error.

```
ERROR/AndroidRuntime(2611): android.content.ActivityNotFoundException: No Activity found to handle Intent { act=android.intent.action.VIEW dat=file:///mnt/sdcard/vvveksperten/ypc.pdf typ=application/pdf }
```

Comment: is there any third party api install on your phone to read pdf????

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Please check your device is any pdf reader application available, I think isn't any..

Just use this code,

```
private void viewPdf(Uri file) {
        Intent intent;
        intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
        intent.setDataAndType(file, "application/pdf");
        try {
            startActivity(intent);
        } catch (ActivityNotFoundException e) {
            // No application to view, ask to download one
            AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
            builder.setTitle("No Application Found");
            builder.setMessage("Download one from Android Market?");
            builder.setPositiveButton("Yes, Please",
                    new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                            Intent marketIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
                            marketIntent
                                    .setData(Uri
                                            .parse("market://details?id=com.adobe.reader"));
                            startActivity(marketIntent);
                        }
                    });
            builder.setNegativeButton("No, Thanks", null);
            builder.create().show();
        }
    }
```

If any pdf reader application not available then this code is download pdf reader from android market, But be sure your device has pre-installed **android-market** application. So I think try this on android device, rather then emulator.

Answer (score 1):

```
    File file = new File(“/sdcard/read.pdf”);

Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);

intent.setDataAndType(Uri.fromFile(file),”application/pdf”);

intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NO_HISTORY);

startActivity(intent);
```

Answer (score 0):

Many (or perhaps most) Android devices don't come with a default PDF Viewer, unlike iOS devices.  That is why you are getting the Exception.  There's no Intent registered with the right IntentFilter.

Please also see this other SO question: [Does android have a built-in PDF viewer?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3969041/does-android-have-a-built-in-pdf-viewer).

The solution is simple: install a PDF Viewer like [Adobe Reader](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.adobe.reader) from Google Play.