# How to open PDF file in Android

Tags: android, pdf

I am trying to open PDF file in android, but cant open it. It will throw an error.

and also if, Is there any code for open PDF file in android, so tell me

Comment: How are you opening it? From code? If so, can we see it? Please read your question and make sure it makes sense before posting.

Comment: Sorry it's mistake, i m asking two questions in one question (2 in 1)Sorry for that. But Now my original question is how to open PDF file in Android device?

Comment: you write things like "it will throw an error". How do you imagine anyone can help you if you don't write anything about the error?

Comment: Unable to open the file.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to render PDF in Android](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2883355/how-to-render-pdf-in-android)