# How to open a office documents, pdf files in android?

Tags: android

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to render PDF in Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2883355/how-to-render-pdf-in-android)

Does any one know how to open a office documents(.doc,.xls) and pdf files in android? I have open a doc from my own app - any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

pls refer this question
[How to render PDF in Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2883355/how-to-render-pdf-in-android)