# What intent would open a pdf from a url?

Tags: android, pdf, android-intent

I am trying to create an intent that would open a pdf file on the web (a url) in a pdf reader.  It seems to only work if the file is local.

I know this is going to depend on whether or not any of the installed apps can handle urls, but since I have several pdf readers installed (some of them claim they can read pdfs on the web) and none of them are responding I wanted to see if there was something wrong with my intent.

Here is what I am currently using:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
intent.setDataAndType(Uri.parse(url), "application/pdf");
```

Thanks

Comment: Have a look at [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2883355/how-to-render-pdf-in-android/) post.

Answer (score 28):

Build a url to the pdf using google docs viewer.  This ends up loading much faster as they don't have to download the file in its entirety before you can display it.

```
private static final String googleDocsUrl = "http://docs.google.com/viewer?url=";

Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
intent.setDataAndType(Uri.parse(googleDocsUrl + url), "text/html");
```

We recently did something similar except we used our own activity with an embedded webview to display the pdf rather than going to the browser.

Comment: What do I pass to "url"? Do I have to upload my document? Does it not work on local (without Internet)?

Comment: Emerald, it won't work without Internet connection. Additionaly your resource has to be somewhere in the Internet.

Comment: Does not work. I get a message saying:

Apologies.
There is no preview available

Comment: @user2260040 I guess you are asking google to load a document that is private to your network. That won't happen.

Comment: This loads a web page that is not optimized for mobile. Are there URL parameters we can set to fix that?

Answer (score 15):

You can simply load the following URL in the Webview

```
webView.loadUrl("https://drive.google.com/viewerng/viewer?embedded=true&url=" + url);
```

Google docs will take care to load the PDF URL.

Comment: That is exactly what I suggested last year.

Comment: Not really - the prefix is different, and it's showing us how to load it into a WebView instead of via Intent.  This isn't quite what littleFluffyKitty was asking, but it's not really worthy of downvotes, and if it works, could be useful to others visiting this question.  No?