# PDF Library for Android - PDFBox?

Tags: android, pdf, pdfbox, renderer, pdfrenderer

Wich libraries exists to use to draw PDF files on Android?

I found PDFBox, that is a JSE Library, and want to know if somehow it can be used to draw the PDFs on Android.

I know Android converts Standard bytecodes into Dalvik Bytecodes, but how it will convert classes like BufferedImage that the framework can convert PDF Files into?

Any suggestion is helpfully, even for paid libraries.

Comment: What do you wan't to do is creating pdf or just showing pdf ?

Comment: Showing. The content come from the editors.

Comment: PDFBox is not suitable http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8980668/how-to-add-pdfbox-to-an-android-project/8997074#8997074

Comment: PDFTron released an android library, it's superb but not its not free.

Comment: RadaePDF lib also is available.

Answer (score 12):

PDF read/writing is a **big** problem for Android. A quick search on Stackoverflow will reveal **many** developers looking for solutions. So far, the most popular solution is to use a webview and [use the google docs engine to render the PDF](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4664791/what-intent-would-open-a-pdf-from-a-url/5342390#5342390)

A second solution, which is a little less 'hacky' is to use one of [these android pdf libraries](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4665957/pdf-parsing-library-for-android/4766335#4766335)

Comment: All these solutions are licensed under GPL, and I need it for commercial use. And I need to have control over the document, so I can't use the google docs engine.

Comment: iText has a commercial Android licence - http://www.itextpdf.com/terms-of-use/

Comment: From iText support staff -- iText is a PDF creator and not a viewer.

Comment: Page not found for the second refered link

Answer (score 9):

If you are an indie developer, you can try PlugPDF. They offer their Android PDF library for free for independent developers and for personal use. http://plugpdf.com/

Disclaimer: I am the Founder & CEO at ePapyrus Inc. which runs plugpdf.com.

Comment: why did this get a -1?

Answer (score 4):

RadaePDF also does offer a Android PDF rendering engine.

---

http://mupdf.com/ released a Android library to PDF reading & writing, it's really very good.

It's a GPL open-source project, but they do commercial licenses.

Answer (score 4):

There is a relative new library http://www.androidpdf.mobi/. It has a one time licence per Android Package Name and worked ok for us, especially for the price.

Comment: Nice, i'll take a look on that

Answer (score 3):

It is a bit expensive but I believe that Adobe Mobile SDK is your product (not open source though)

Comment: I already used Adobe Reader Mobile SDK (RMSDK) at one project, but it's license is a bit expensive to afford general uses on other projects.

Answer (score 2):

Qoppa have some Android libraries - have you had a look at them?

Comment: I didn't find anything for Android on their website

Comment: http://www.qoppa.com/android/pdfsdk/