# NoClassDefFoundError in pdfbox android studio

Tags: android, android-studio, noclassdeffounderror, pdfbox

**I want to use pdfbox in my android application.but I faced this error:**

> FATAL EXCEPTION: main
>                                                                              Process: com.android.app.spritzing, PID: 12534
>                                                                              java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Failed resolution of:
>   Ljava/awt/color/ColorSpace;*

**my gradle.build file is like this:**

```
> apply plugin: 'com.android.application'  android {
> 
>     compileSdkVersion 24
>     buildToolsVersion "24.0.0"
>     defaultConfig {
>         applicationId "com.android.app.spritzing"
>         minSdkVersion 15
>         targetSdkVersion 24
>         versionCode 1
>         versionName "1.0"
>     }
>     buildTypes {
>         release {
>             minifyEnabled false
>             proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
>         }
>     }
>     packagingOptions {
>         exclude 'META-INF/DEPENDENCIES'
>         exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE'
>         exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE'
>         exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE.txt'
>         exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE.txt'
>         exclude 'META-INF/maven/edu.ucar/udunits/pom.xml'
>         exclude 'META-INF/maven/edu.ucar/udunits/pom.properties'
>         exclude 'META-INF/maven/edu.ucar/netcdf4/pom.xml'
>         exclude 'META-INF/maven/edu.ucar/netcdf4/pom.properties'
>         exclude 'META-INF/maven/edu.ucar/cdm/pom.xml'
>         exclude 'META-INF/maven/edu.ucar/cdm/pom.properties'
>         exclude 'META-INF/maven/edu.ucar/grib/pom.xml'
>         exclude 'META-INF/maven/edu.ucar/grib/pom.properties'
>         exclude 'META-INF/maven/org.apache.xmlbeans/xmlbeans/pom.xml'
>         exclude 'META-INF/maven/org.apache.xmlbeans/xmlbeans/pom.properties'
>         exclude 'META-INF/maven/edu.ucar/httpservices/pom.xml'
>         exclude 'META-INF/maven/edu.ucar/httpservices/pom.properties'
>     }  } 
> 
> dependencies {
>     compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
>     testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
>     compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:24.2.1'
>     compile 'org.apache.pdfbox:pdfbox:2.0.4'  }
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to add PDFBox to an Android project or suggest alternative](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8980668/how-to-add-pdfbox-to-an-android-project-or-suggest-alternative)

Answer (score 1):

Your library pdfbox uses a class `java.awt.color.ColorSpace` that is defined in Java SDK, and this class is not included in Android SDK

Comment: I think that this is a bad idea

Comment: @Rastinof Use an Android port of PDFBox.

Comment: Thanks @mkl. Link to [PdfBox-Android](https://github.com/TomRoush/PdfBox-Android) based on [PDFBox](https://pdfbox.apache.org) library open source.