# unable convert pdf to image in android

Tags: android, android-layout, android-intent

I tried to show content pdf file in my layout (customize). I used Pdf-renderer convert to image (search google solution...) but it have problem, I fixed project but it's still error..

my code:

```
     try{

        PDFPage mpdfpage;
        PDFFile mpdffile;
        Bitmap bitmap = mpdfpage.getImage(100, 100, null, null, true, true);

    }catch(Exception w)
    {

    }
```

but have problem: "The type java.awt.Image cannot be resolved. It is indirectly referenced from required .class files"

Comment: Is that `android.graphics.Bitmap`?

Answer (score 0):

The `java.awt` packages are not available on Android. You need another PDF renderer that doesn't rely on them.

**UPDATE**:
See if one of the renderers in the answers to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5952626/pdf-library-for-android-pdfbox) suits your needs.