# Open PDF from within Android application using any installed reader

Tags: android, pdf

I'm new to programing and trying to open a pdf to view in my app.  I'm not trying to include a reader "in" my app, but send it to what ever pdf reader the user has.

I've searched through all the questions here and found this one  [Render pdf](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2883355/how-to-render-pdf-in-android).

I made a test app and it worked!  The only problem is the end user has to save/launch the file from their SD card.  I would like to include the PDF's "inside" the app.

So my question is:

1. Where should I store the pdfs?
2. How would I direct the app to them?

This is a snippet code for launching from the SD card, I would guess it's what needs changed:

```
public void onClick(View v)
{File file = new File    ("/sdcard/download/2011_BASIC.pdf");
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Wow I can't believe no one answered this!  I have found the answers my-self.  I am posting them to help others and save them the time it took me to figure it out.

Question 1. The files should be stored in the /res/raw folder (make the folder if it is not there)

Question 2.  The path is simply ("/app_name/pdf_name")  quick note use %20 for spaces in the apps name.

-Nick

Answer (score 1):

The files can be stored anywhere you want.
Though you can achieve the thing that you want using the following code, it works for sure.

```
File openfile = new File(root+ file.getName());

Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);

Uri data = Uri.fromFile(openfile);

intent.setDataAndType(data,"application/pdf");

startActivity(intent);
```