#  Connect myApp with PDF Viewer

Tags: android, pdf

my app is downloading a pdf-file to my download path 
and then i want to open my PDF within a new Intent

but just my reader is open
no pdf file

this is my code to open the reader

```
        Uri oUri = Uri.fromFile(proofFile); 
        Intent iIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW); 
        iIntent.setDataAndType(oUri, "application/pdf"); 
        iIntent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP); 
        startActivity(iIntent);
```

Answer (score 0):

By default there is no PDF viewer installed on Android, although some HTC phones come with  an app that is capable of reading PDF. So first check if you have an app that can read PDF and then read [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2883355/how-to-render-pdf-in-android/) on how to open it.