# How to read variable from the other Activity

Tags: android, bundle

I have two activities.( activity 1 and activity 2)
activity 1 has a public Array like this

```
 public byte[][] arrtest=new byte[3][1024];
```

I call activity 2 and  I want to get value from arrtest in activity 2.

How can I do this?

Comment: You can pass it in intent.

Comment: pass arrtest array through intent

Comment: Pass it in bundle or intent OR declare it as static and then use it anywhere

Comment: Intent won't work if size is too large. Save it somewhere. And then just pass the path to another `Activity`

Comment: use shared preferences

Comment: I'm new in android. please give me a code. I defined it as static . but when I wrote activity1.arrtest is undefined in activiy2.

Comment: (for pass arrtest through intent. ) activity2 wants call activity1 and get value. but I think intent is for pass value to activity1

Comment: Thank you veru much. I defined it static and now I can see it in activity2

Comment: @Fatemah store your byte array into a file. You can use this code from here http://stackoverflow.com/a/6828668/842607 and then send the file path to another `Activity`. You can check comments from http://stackoverflow.com/a/31426584/842607 for what kind of error you can get. So store it in device then send the file path to another activity. Retrieve byte array from using file path and do your proceeding stuffs

Answer (score 0):

Pass array to another acivity and then use it.Check out this answer

https://stackoverflow.com/a/7257726/3789993

Comment: Thank you very much AbhayBohra

Comment: @AbhayBohra What if byte array size is more than 500 kb?? This solution won't work.

Comment: Use a singleton class. You save the array in a variable of your singleton

Answer (score 0):

You have to use bundle or adding it into intent.

```
    Intent intent = new Intent(view.getContext(), ApplicationActivity.class);
                        intent.putExtra("key", value);
                        startActivity(intent);
```

invoked activity.

```
Intent intent = getIntent();
Bundle bundle = intent.getExtras();

if(bundle != null){
    mealId = bundle.getInt("key");
}
```