# Embed PDF Viewer for PhoneGap application

Tags: android, ios, cordova, sencha-touch

How can I embed a PDF viewer for a phonegap application? I have decided to use PhoneGap + Sencha Touch to develop an application for iOS and Android.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's not much documentation for mixing PhoneGap and ObjC, but [here is some example cod](https://github.com/purplecabbage/cleavage)e that lets you embed PhoneGap with an ObjectiveC-Application. For the PDF viewer, you can either use basic ones like Apple's QuickLook or UIWebView, or more advanced ones like PSPDFKit.

For Android, you could [simply search for an Intent that is capable of displaying pdf](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2883355/how-to-render-pdf-in-android) (like Adobe's official Reader for Android) or integrate a full PDF viewer yourself. [There's an open source project for that](http://andpdf.sourceforge.net/), but it looks not quite complete. Or check out [apv](http://code.google.com/p/apv/), or [droidreader](http://code.google.com/p/droidreader/), which is GPLv3.

Answer (score 3):

I only have iOS phonegap experience. The solution that has worked for me is to make a plugin that pops up a native webview that uses iOS native pdf viewer. The way to get this to work is to follow the instructions on this website.

http://spin.atomicobject.com/2010/12/07/updating-phonegap-s-childbrowser-plugin-to-handle-local-files/

This link modifies an existing plugin, "Child browser" to use the native webview display pdf's. The original chilbrowser plugin can be found [here](https://github.com/purplecabbage/phonegap-plugins/tree/master/iPhone/ChildBrowser).

To give you more of an idea of what it will be like, here is my particular javascript call that I put into my sencha application.

```
 PhoneGap.exec("ChildBrowserCommand.showFilePage", GlobalVar.localRoot + "/" + record.get("FilePath"));
```

This is inside the handler for the buttonTap inside the sencha, pressing the button will then call the objective C method "showFilePage". The parameter is the filepath that the plugin will use.

Here is the Objective C part (again, you should follow the links for full instructions)

```
    - (void) showFilePage:(NSMutableArray*)arguments withDict:(NSMutableDictionary*)options // args: url
{   
    NSLog(@"showFilePage entered: ");
    if(childBrowser == NULL)
    {
        childBrowser = [[ ChildBrowserViewController alloc ] initWithScale:FALSE ];
        childBrowser.delegate = self;
    }




    PhoneGapViewController* cont = (PhoneGapViewController*)[ super appViewController ];
    childBrowser.supportedOrientations = cont.supportedOrientations;
    [ cont presentModalViewController:childBrowser animated:YES ];

    NSString *path = (NSString*) [arguments objectAtIndex:0];
    NSLog(@"Our argument 0 is: %@",[arguments objectAtIndex:0]);

    NSLog(@"The url is: %@",path);
    [childBrowser loadFileURL:path];

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Hi just use HTML5 object tag, you can add,swf, pdf etc..