# Parse PDF from Amazon S3 storage using phonegap and javascript

Tags: javascript, pdf, cordova, amazon-s3

I am trying to write my first PhoneGap application and want to read and parse the contents of a PDF that is located on the Amazon S3 storage.  I have used tools like iTextPdf to create Android apps to parse PDF files but my knowledge of javascript and Phonegap is limited.  I know Amazon S3 has REST requests you can call to get files but I can't seem to find any examples of how to do this with Javascript.  I would appreciate if anyone could tell me if this is even possible and if so provide some example code or direction to where I could find the answer on how to do this.

Thanks

Comment: This is the first time I have asked this question.  My other questions in the past have been Android related and nothing to do with the question I have asked above.

Comment: About your question, you might find something useful [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6979344/embed-pdf-viewer-for-phonegap-application).

Comment: Sorry I didn't understand your comment.  I will go through my past questions and accept any answers that I used.