# Open PDF with PhoneGap in Android

Tags: android, pdf, cordova

I need open an PDF file that is in an url. I need open it with an PDF Viewer...

It is possible?

Thanks for all.

Best regards.

Comment: Were you able to find any library or any workaround for opening PDF with Phonegap in Android? I am also stuck there.

Answer (score 6):

I suggest using the [ChildBrowser plugin](https://build.phonegap.com/blog/childbrowser-plugin) and using Google's viewer to actualy open the PDF (since Android doesn't have a default PDF viewer).

So you can open a PDF like this:

```
onclick='window.plugins.childBrowser.showWebPage(encodeURI("http://docs.google.com/viewer?url=' + pdfLink + '"));
```

Comment: Can we alter this method to work with a PDF stored on the device?

Comment: As of version 2.3 no need for installing plugin http://docs.phonegap.com/en/2.3.0/cordova_inappbrowser_inappbrowser.md.html#InAppBrowser

Comment: InAppBrowser doesn't work for PDF's on Android. works well on IOS though.

Answer (score 1):

in android (i don't know phonegap) there are many pdf viewer libraries.

like [Android-Pdf-Viewer-Library](https://github.com/jblough/Android-Pdf-Viewer-Library)

or [Droid Text](http://code.google.com/p/droidtext/)

or [MuPDF](http://www.mupdf.com/)

or [APV Pdf Viewer](http://code.google.com/p/apv/)

if you develope your application commercial and don't want to pay any money

use first one.

Comment: Thanks friend, but i need it for PhoneGap.

Comment: in Cordova/PhoneGap this means you will have to create a plugin out of one of those