# How to open a PDF file that is in local file system (Cordova)?

Tags: android, pdf, cordova, pdf-viewer

I have been looking at these entries ([Link 1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16795172/phonegap-inappbrowser-display-pdf-2-7-0), [Link 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2655972/android-webview-pdf?lq=1), [Link 3](http://www.giovesoft.com/2011/08/download-and-open-pdf-with-phonegap.html)) to solve this issue. These links have been helpful but not quite there.

The app i'm working on creates and stores PDF files in local file system. The file locations is similar to this `file:///storage/emulated/0/myDir/file.pdf`. Now, my question is how can I open/view  PDFs using `InAppBrowser`, `GoogleDocs` or any other tools?