# Can't use pdf.js viewer for local file:// on Android, works on iOS

Tags: android, cordova, xmlhttprequest, cors, pdf.js

Using the viewer from [pdf.js](https://github.com/mozilla/pdf.js) I successfully managed to open a local pdf file with the [InAppBrowser](https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-inappbrowser). The following code works without flaws on iOS: the InAppBrowser opens and displays the pdf with the viewer!

```
window.resolveLocalFileSystemURL(fileURL, function (file) {
    window.open('lib/pdf.js-master/web/viewer.html?file=' + file.toURL(), '_blank', 'location=no')
}, fail);
```

`file.toURL()` renders to something like `file:///blabla/bla`.
However, on Android the pdf fails to load, giving the console error

```
"XMLHttpRequest cannot load file:///android_asset/www/lib/pdf.js-master/web/locale/locale.properties. Cross origin requests are only supported for HTTP.", source: file:///android_asset/www/lib/pdf.js-master/web/viewer.html?file=file:///storage/emulated/0/Android/data/xxxxxxxxx/cache/677.pdf
```

and there isn't even a `www/lib/pdf.js-master/web/locale/locale.properties` file... I don't know if this has anything to do with the problem, but I'm including it here.
But this is followed by the error

```
"XMLHttpRequest cannot load file:///storage/emulated/0/Android/data/xxxxxxxxx/cache/677.pdf. Cross origin requests are only supported for HTTP.", source: file:///android_asset/www/lib/pdf.js-master/web/viewer.html?file=file:///storage/emulated/0/Android/data/xxxxxxxxx/cache/677.pdf
```

which absolutely has something to do with the problem.
Resulting in the following screen.
[image]

I don't know how to fix the error. And once again, it works flawlessly on iOS! What can I do to make it work on android? How can I enable cross origin requests for `file:///`? Is this the problem?
Thanks for any help.

Comment: Does the file exist in the path ?

Comment: It does! I can successfully do `file.moveTo(destination, 'newname');`

Comment: I noticed you're on Simulator. Does this work on real Android device?

Comment: `file.moveTo(destination, 'newname');` works, I know that from earlier this day. About the issue above, I don't know since I don't own an Android device myself. But my guess would be that it has nothing to do with emulation.

Comment: Any chance you can try [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19471577/how-to-open-a-pdf-file-that-is-in-local-file-system-cordova) ?

Comment: I will try it and see if it works. But this is not the solution I want. I want the pdf to open *inside* the app, not with an external app.

Comment: Yes this works. The file does exist! But once again, this is not the solution I want since this opens the pdf externally.

Answer (score 1):

Have you explicitly enabled your webview to request files from a URL via javascript?

This works by default for Android API 15 and below. However, the default is set to `false` for API 16 and above, which means that you must call:

```
setAllowFileAccessFromFileURLs(true);
```

Here is a full example:

```
// create a webview with javascript enabled
WebView mWebView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webview);
mWebView.setWebChromeClient(new WebChromeClient());
mWebView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
mWebView.getSettings().setAllowFileAccessFromFileURLs(true);

// finally load your pdf.js html file with the correct parameters
mWebView.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/pdfviewer/...");
```

Then to make it work with InAppBrowser, add the following after line 657 in [src/android/InAppBrowser.java](https://github.com/cjpearson/cordova-plugin-inappbrowser/blob/ebac47b5619163559faf1ce4eb61ebf75485ef6c/src/android/InAppBrowser.java#L657):

```
settings.setAllowFileAccessFromFileURLs(true);
```

You can also have a look at this issue for a different approach to override the WebView settings: [Building custom WebView With Cordova 5.0 in Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31536711/building-custom-webview-with-cordova-5-0-in-android)