# How to View PDF Files in Android WebBrowser using Java Script in Phonegap?

Tags: android, cordova, pdf-viewer

I have to open pdf file in android using phonegap.
I have tried in iOS, it works fine but does not work same code on android device

Following is code which works fine on iOS

```
function Application() {
}
Application.prototype.Run = function() {
    if (device.uuid == "e0101010d38bde8e6740011221af335301010333" || device.uuid == "e0908060g38bde8e6740011221af335301010333") {
        alert("Not Supported in Simulator.");
    }
    else {
        var infoDiv = document.getElementById("infoField");
        var path = this.getWorkingFolder().replace('http://', 'file://') + "sample.pdf";
        infoDiv.innerText = path;

        if (device.platform === 'Android') {
            window.open(path, '_system');
        }
        else {
            window.open(path, '_blank');
        }
    }
}

Application.prototype.getWorkingFolder = function() {
    var path = window.location.href.replace('index.html', '');
    return path;
}
function onDeviceReady() {
    alert('OnDevice Ready called');
    //navigator.splashscreen.hide();
    document.getElementById('btnOpenPDF').onclick = function() {
        var app = new Application();
        app.Run();
    }
}
document.addEventListener("deviceready", onDeviceReady, false);
```

Comment: Can you post the code?

Comment: This may help you- http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16795172/phonegap-inappbrowser-display-pdf-2-7-0

Comment: It works same as mine code but not working

Comment: In Android WebView, you can't loading pdf file directly. You must use 3rd app to view pdf file or use lib to support that