# open pdf using jquery mobile

Tags: jquery-mobile, ibm-mobilefirst

How to open a PDF using jQuery mobile.
I'm using worklight 6.o and the adapter returns the content of PDF,
var content = 'some PDF content' -- which i will get from the apadapter
contentType = 'PDF' -- which i will get from the adapter.
I have content and contentType, based on this, I need to open the PDF, if the contentType is PDF or word,if the contentType is msword.

```
function onSuccessDownloadAdapter (results) {
          try {
              if(results.invocationResult.isSuccessful){
              if(results.invocationResult.stat == "ok"){
                  var content = results.invocationResult.content;
                  var contentType = results.invocationResult.contentType;
                 var embed = '<embed src=data:'+contentType+';base64,'+content+'>';
                     $("#dataContent").append(embed);
              }
              else{
                  alert("Stat fail:"+message);
                  WL.Logger.debug("Stat fail:"+message);    
              }
              }
              else{
                  alert("No connection");
                  WL.Logger.debug("downlaodAdapter onSuccess:: noConnection");  

              }  
              busyInd.hide();
          } catch (e) {
              busyInd.hide();
            displayError(e.toString());
          }

}
```

This is working in browser, but not in mobile.

Comment: And add more how; how do you get the file and how do you want to view the file.

Comment: I found this link somewhere , try this. May be it helps you.  http://pcgeek.ch/programming/jquery-mobile/open-pdf-file-with-android-phonegap-jqm/  Please elaborate you question for more understanding.

Comment: Im testing on real device HTC, its not opening and no error also.

Comment: What does msword got to do with mobile?

Comment: I need to open PDF or word document depending on the content Type.Both are not working in the real device

Answer (score 0):

Android's WebView does not allow embedding PDF or Word documents by default.

See: [Phonegap InAppBrowser display pdf 2.7.0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16795172/phonegap-inappbrowser-display-pdf-2-7-0)

Comment: I have used like this window.open('data:application/pdf;base64,'+escape(PDFdata), '_system', 'location=yes'), throwing an error, InAppviewer unable to load the URL

Answer (score 0):

Please take a look at: https://github.com/markeeftb/FileOpener

Plugin opens external application which handles the preview of the document.

Comment: if I get the content of the PDF from adapter, how can i use this FileOpener