# Reading a pdf file in android and IOS phonegap app

Tags: android, ios, pdf, phonegap-plugins, phonegap-build

I am working on a **phonegap-app**. I am using the website 'build.phonegap.com' to build the apk(android) or IOS(ipa) file. The app basically uses **html5**, **css3**, **jquery mobile** and **jquery** only. I tried the code below in my config.xml file,
`<plugin name="com.kernix.pdfviewer" spec="1.1.0" source="pgb" />`
which i found [here](https://build.phonegap.com/plugins).
In my document.ready in js file, i have written something like,
`window.open('http://www.example.com/foldername/document.pdf', '_blank');`
But its not working. Am i doing anything wrong?. please help, thank you.

Comment: Which version are you compiling with? Please add that information to your post. If you are not using a version, please ad that to your post and respond.

Comment: The phonegap version i am using is 3.6.3

Comment: Are you aware Beginning May 9, 2016, Google Play will block publishing of any new apps or updates that use pre-4.1.1 versions of Apache Cordova. [NOTES](https://github.com/jessemonroy650/top-phonegap-mistakes/blob/master/android-block-pre-4.1.1.md)

Comment: No..but i have an app on playstore built with same version mentioned above. Should i try updating the phonegap version??

Comment: Ok you mean my new app must be in the updated phonegap version. I got  the point.

Comment: Okay. I think you understand you MUST move to cli-5.1.1 or better. You will then be required to use the *whitelist* system and plugin. So I need to ask: Is this your first hybrid App? Are you using the Desktop App? Are you using [CLI, SDK or Build](https://github.com/jessemonroy650/top-phonegap-mistakes/blob/master/new-to-Phonegap.md#001) ? Please do not assume the answer, please read the link. Once you have answer the question *in the post*, respond in the comments so I know you have added information to the post.

Answer (score 1):

I tried the code below which worked for me, i got it [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26304729/not-able-to-launch-a-pdf-file-in-inappbrowser-in-android)
`window.open(encodeURI('https://docs.google.com/gview?embedded=true&url=http://www.your-server.com/files/your_file.pdf'), '_blank', 'location=yes,EnableViewPortScale=yes');`

Comment: But i dont know if we can open a pdf file without using `https://docs.google.com/gview?embedded=true&url`.

Comment: Now the problem with above code is, the pdf is opened with google's view and it also lets the user download the pdf. If possible, i do not want the pdf to be downloadable.

Answer (score 0):

The plugin `com.kernix.pdfviewer` supports only in ios, it won't work in android.

If u want to work it in ios you should use the following js code after `deviceready` event fired.

```
PDFViewer.open("file://sample.pdf","sample.pdf", function (msg) {
    console.log(msg);
});
```

To read the pdf files in both platforms use following plugin

https://github.com/siegfriedbolz/cordova-plugin-file-opener2/tree/dd31ffa

Hope it helps u.

Comment: No, its not working. I got the below code from https://build.phonegap.com/plugins/959 where i was redirected from github link you provided above `<plugin name="io.github.siegfriedbolz.cordova.plugins.fileopener2" spec="1.0.5" source="pgb" />
`

Comment: I am actually trying to alert, in the onDeviceReady function, but i am actually not even getting the alert saying "in onDeviceReady".

Comment: I have also added the cordova.js file in my js folder and mentioned it's path in index.html file

Comment: are u running this in which device? means platform?