# inAppBrowser ANDROID reading PDF problems

Tags: android, cordova, pdf

Coming here, desperately, I really need help with an answer for my question... I do have a inAppBrowser and my can't ready a PDF (after accessing pdf view). I use cordova, phonegap. I know that I can't read a PDF because for android IAB didn't implemented a viewer, but, how can i use plugin FileTransfer? or open(url, _system). From the start, I call my app as open(url, _blank). If I'm pressing on PDF link, want my IAB to be transformed in _system, but when I go back, want my app still be _blank. Or, if I'm accessing a PDF link, to be downloaded, using FileTransfer. I had tried this 2 codes:

**FileTransfer:**

```
var fileTransfer = new FileTransfer();
fileTransfer.download(url, "");
```

If I'm accessing PDF link, nothing happens...

**And _system:**

```
cordova.InAppBrowser.open(url, '_system', 'location=no');
```

This code works fine, but! After I'm accessing PDF link, IAB -> transforms into _system, but when I go back and I press on PDF link again, nothing happens anymore... (so what I want is my IAB, to be _blank again)

Thank you !

Comment: please refer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26304729/not-able-to-launch-a-pdf-file-in-inappbrowser-in-android
Similar question.

Comment: I think is not really the same question...