# how to open .pdf file form android file path appended to Google Docs View

Tags: angular, cordova, pdf, ionic2, ionic3

i am using [InAppBrower](https://ionicframework.com/docs/native/in-app-browser/) to open pdf file it is not supporting the .pdf file so i choose to use gview for supporting it

> My file path file:///data/user/0/com.schneider.and/files/Attendance_Policy_Ver_1.0.pdf

here is my code for inappbrower

```
//the below code works file
// var url = https://docs.google.com/gview?embedded=true&url=http://unec.edu.az/application/uploads/2014/12/pdf-sample.pdf

//the below code is not working showing blank screen 
    var url = https://docs.google.com/gview?embedded=true&url=file:///data/user/0/com.schneider.and/files/Attendance_Policy_Ver_1.0.pdf ;


//my inappbrowser code
    const browser = this.iab.create(url, '_blank', 'location=yes
,EnableViewPortScale=yes');
```

i am getting blank screen in my inappbrowser window.

Answer (score 0):

First of all refer this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26310942/5213405) on launching pdf files in `Inappbrowser` in Android.

I think you cannot give your local file path in that way.

`InAppBrowser` is supported for web content mostly. its in a way similar to Androids `WebView`.

Quoting from [Inappbrowser - Apache Cordova](https://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/latest/reference/cordova-plugin-inappbrowser/index.html),

> - You can show helpful articles, videos, and web resources inside of your app. Users can view web pages without leaving your app.
> - The InAppBrowser window behaves like a standard web browser, and can't access Cordova APIs. For this reason, the InAppBrowser is recommended if you need to load third-party (untrusted) content

Do check [this](https://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/latest/reference/cordova-plugin-inappbrowser/#local-urls--source-is-in-the-app-package-) format for opening Local URIs (HTML pages).

You can use [ngCordova-FileOpener2](http://ngcordova.com/docs/plugins/fileOpener2/) for opening files (including pdf) from the device storage. This uses default application for opening particular type of file.

Working code snippet -

```
<body >
    <ion-pane>
      <ion-header-bar class="bar-stable">
        <h1 class="title">Ionic Blank Starter</h1>
      </ion-header-bar>
      <ion-content ng-controller="FileOpenerController">
        <button class="button button-full button-positive" ng-click="openPDF()">
          Open PDF File
        </button>
      </ion-content>
    </ion-pane>
</body>
```

Then in JavaScript file use this -

```
app.controller('FileOpenerController', function($scope, $cordovaFileOpener2, $ionicPlatform) {

    $scope.openPDF= function() {
        $cordovaFileOpener2.open(
            '/sdcard/Download/109.pdf',
            'application/pdf'
        ).then(function() {
            console.log('Success');
        }, function(err) {
        console.log('An error occurred: ' + JSON.stringify(err));
        });
    };           
});
```

Full tutorial along with the code can be found [here](http://www.gajotres.net/how-to-open-a-file-using-its-default-application-in-ionic-framework/2/).

Comment: I tried your answer but i am not able to open the pdf file i am not even getting blank screen i am getting balck screen for 2 to 3 sec and then closing automatically

Comment: Did you try the tutorial in this [link](http://www.gajotres.net/how-to-open-a-file-using-its-default-application-in-ionic-framework/2/) ?? (same as the one posted in answer)