# How to open PDF with in app browser Ionic Vue?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, ionic-framework

I have a problem with read or view pdf in app with ionic vue. I have already try to use library of all vue pdf viewer, but until now no one is supported with vue 3 and ionic.

At least i have tried using in app browser ionic native, but its also not working, only showing blank page.

My code:

```
<template>
  <ion-page>
    <ion-header>
      <ion-toolbar>
        <ion-buttons slot="start">
          <ion-back-button
            :default-href="pageDefaultBackLink"
          ></ion-back-button>
        </ion-buttons>
        <ion-title>{{ document.judul }}</ion-title>
        <ion-buttons slot="end">
          <slot name="actions-end"></slot>
        </ion-buttons>
      </ion-toolbar>
    </ion-header>
    <ion-content >
        <in-app-browser/>
    </ion-content>
  </ion-page>
</template>

<script>
import { IonPage, IonHeader, IonToolbar, IonTitle, IonContent, IonBackButton} from '@ionic/vue';
import axios from 'axios'
import { onMounted, ref } from 'vue'
import { format } from 'date-fns'
import { useRoute } from 'vue-router'
import { InAppBrowser } from '@ionic-native/in-app-browser';

export default  {
  name: 'Tab1',
  components: {IonHeader, IonToolbar, IonTitle, IonContent, IonPage, IonBackButton, InAppBrowser},
  setup() {
    let document = ref([])

    const options = [{
      location: 'no',
      zoom: 'no',
      hideurlbar: 'yes',
      toolbarposition: 'bottom'
    }]

    InAppBrowser.create('http://www.africau.edu/images/default/sample.pdf', '_self', options)
    
    const route = useRoute()

    onMounted(() => {
      getDocument()
    })

    function getDocument(){
      axios.get(`document/${route.params.id}`)
      .then(response => {
        document.value = response.data
      }).catch(error => {
          console.log(error.response.data)
      })
    }

    return {
      document,
      getDocument,
      format,
    }
  }
}
</script>
```

Maybe there is have another better library choice for view pdf in app with ionic vue. Thanks before.

[image: No error, and show blank]

Comment: What's the error when you're doing this? First, change the single quotes around your URL, by this ```'http://www.africau.edu/images/default/sample.pdf'```

Comment: There is no error, and the app show white blank

Comment: I have already add console log screenshot, no error

Comment: Could you try using this import ```import { InAppBrowser } from '@ionic-native/in-app-browser/ngx'```

Comment: return error [vue-cli-service] This dependency was not found:
[vue-cli-service] * @angular/core in ./node_modules/@ionic-native/in-app-browser/ngx/index.js
[vue-cli-service] To install it, you can run: npm install --save @angular/core

Because i dont user angular

Comment: Sorry, didn't see you were using Vue. Did you try using ```window.open(URL)``` ? I can't see any problem in your implementation, or try using ```InAppBrowser.create('http://www.africau.edu/images/default/sample.pdf', '_system')```

Comment: yes, its work with _system, but its will lauch outside the app. I want the pdf showing under the ionheader, at ion content. I use _self and its didnt work, showing blank.

Comment: Did you try with ```_blank```

Comment: i tried, _blank will open pdf outside app.

Comment: In your ```config.xml```, do you have this tag ```<allow-navigation href="*" />```

Comment: i just add that line in my config.xml, but when i run app with: ionic capacitor run android -l --host=192.168.1.4, the config.xml is reset

Comment: This command opens Android Studio, then check for the config.xml in Android Studio, and override this value, before you run the app on your device

Comment: i already try add that line in android studio, at path folder app-> res->xml->config.xml. But its still blank :(

Comment: `<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?>
<widget version="1.0.0" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/ns/widgets" xmlns:cdv="http://cordova.apache.org/ns/1.0">
  <access origin="*" />
  <allow-navigation href="*" />

  <feature name="SitewaertsDocumentViewer">
    <param name="android-package" value="de.sitewaerts.cordova.documentviewer.DocumentViewerPlugin"/>
  </feature>

  <feature name="InAppBrowser">
    <param name="android-package" value="org.apache.cordova.inappbrowser.InAppBrowser"/>
  </feature>
</widget>`

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26304729/not-able-to-launch-a-pdf-file-in-inappbrowser-in-android  i see this question, i think in app browser cant show pdf

Comment: So i use window.open() and its work. Thanks for your help sir @shinici