# Phonegap PDF Viewer or Open pdf file from local for Windows Phone 8

Tags: cordova

I am working in phonegap for windows phone 8 app. Currently I am stuck with opening a pdf file from **LOCAL AREA** (like in phone >> documents >> myfolder>>1.pdf)

I tried in js

```
document.addEventListener("deviceready", deviceready, false);

function deviceready() {
   window.open('.documents/myfolder/1.pdf', '_blank', 'location=no');
}
```

but it doesn't work.

I also tried

```
window.open('**documents**/myfolder/1.pdf', '_blank', 'location=no');
```

and

```
window.open('**/documents**/myfolder/1.pdf', '_blank', 'location=no');
```

but neither works.

Otherwise, if there is a PDF viewer plugin for phonegap and WP8, please share the link.

Note: I have adobe pdf reader installed on the phone

Answer (score 1):

Try any of the following that works for you.

```
window.open('http://www.example.com/test.pdf', '_system', 'location=yes');

window.open('http://www.example.com/test.pdf', '_blank', 'location=no,closebuttoncaption=Close,enableViewportScale=yes');
```

Check this Google PDF viewer

```
window.open('https://docs.google.com/viewer?url=http://www.example.com/test.pdf&embedded=true', '_blank', 'location=yes');
```

Read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16795172/phonegap-inappbrowser-display-pdf-2-7-0/18596650#18596650) , [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24424156/cordova-pdf-viewer) and [this](http://me.eekay.nl/index.php/2014/how-to-properly-download-and-show-a-frickin-pdf-in-cordova-cli/). Hope it will help you.