# Opening local pdf in native browser android

Tags: android, pdf, browser

I am working on an application in which i want to load my local pdf file on web browser. Like in web view i want to show my pdf file. For local web browser loading i used the following code for opening any link.

```
String googleUrl = "http://docs.google.com/gview?embedded=true&url=";
            Log.d(TAG, googleUrl + MenuUrl);
            Intent browserIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse(googleUrl + MenuUrl));
            startActivity(browserIntent);
```

Answer (score 0):

Google chrome can open pdf files because of plugins. Android browser cannot do the same. Though this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23152202/2777227) seems to answer your question.