# Opening a local PDF

Tags: android, ios, iphone, cordova, ionic2

I'm working on an Ionic2 app, building simultaneously for both Android and iOS. My app requires a PDF, stored on the device to be opened. I have the PDF stored in my www folder and I'm using the InAppBrowser plugin to open the same. This works perfectly fine on iOS, but it does not on Android, as it throws up an error saying the application does not have write permissions.

Any help on this would be appreciated.

Comment: Do these help? https://www.quora.com/How-do-you-display-PDF-files-inside-an-Android-application-instead-of-loading-in-WebView-by-appending-PDF-URL-with-a-Google-DOCs-Url-and-launching-a-third-party-PDF-rendering-application-installed-in-the-device-Are-there-any-good-free-PDF-rendering-libraries-available

Comment: @Steve I would like to use the same code base for both Android and iOS. Is that possible?

Comment: That's what the /merges folder is for. See how I used it here: https://iphonedevlog.wordpress.com/2014/06/20/using-cordova-3-5-cli-on-mac-os-x-mavericks-to-build-android-apps/

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Phonegap InAppBrowser display pdf 2.7.0](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16795172/phonegap-inappbrowser-display-pdf-2-7-0)