# Ionic - InAppBrowser browsing HTML files and navigating to PDF files

Tags: android, pdf, ionic-framework, inappbrowser

Following scenario:

I am using the InAppBrowser plugin from Ionic Native and I am navigating to a local html.. I open the first html in the InAppBrowser with the code:

```
this.inappbrowser.create("files/index.htm");
```

The index.htm contains links to some pdf documents. Its a known issue that the InAppBrowser can't display/open a pdf file on an Android device. How can I tell the InAppBrowser to open documents with the Document Viewer from Ionic Native or something else that can display it? Or is there a way to subscribe to an event and catch the url if I click on an link to a pdf?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can't directly open PDF in external App. You can try [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16795172/phonegap-inappbrowser-display-pdf-2-7-0) solution.

Comment: I intend to navigate to multiple PDF files which are structured in the index.html. I have to open the html file to navigate to the pdf files.

Comment: i don't think it can be possible without downloading the pdf

Comment: It won't be a problem if i download the pdf first. But it is important to open it/navigate to it through the index.htm