# View downloaded PDFs inside PhoneGap/Android app

Tags: android, pdf, cordova

I'm working on an Android app that (ideally) will download PDF files and display them without leaving the app and going to a viewer application.

[This Stack Overflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6079923/open-pdf-in-android-app) solves this problem, but forces users to leave the app and open a 3rd party application (which users would have to download) to see the PDF. This is definitely not ideal: I want to accomplish this within my own app.

Some details that might help:

I'm building the app with [Phonegap](http://phonegap.com/) (also called Cordova), which means all of my code is in html and javascript, but it compiles natively to the Android. This means that if there is a javascript library that allows web browsers to display PDFs, my app will be able to display them too. I've looked over the [jsPDF library](http://jspdf.com/), which allows programmers to create new PDFs using html and javascript and display them in a webpage. However, I don't want to create a new PDF, just display one that already exists; it doesn't seem like jsPDF has an option for this. Is there a similar library that might work?

Phonegap can also access the Android's in-app web browser, but I don't think this browser can view PDFs. However, it's possible there's a plugin to this browser that would enable it to do so... Has anyone heard of one?

Any other ideas would be welcome. I'm stuck on this :/

Comment: Have you considered Mozilla's pdf.js library? https://github.com/mozilla/pdf.js/

Comment: I looked at it, but I eventually gave up on it: There is no documentation and neither of the examples they provide worked when I ran them. I assumed it wasn't functional... Is it?

Comment: I've never used it on Android in a webview, but I have recently got it working on a website.

Comment: Great! I'll take another look at it then. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Try a rendering library like pdf.js to view the pdf in your app.

Another alternative is - assuming your app user will have/need internet connectivity - using the online Google Document viewer functionality in combination with Phonegap's InAppBrowser plugin like in [this StackOverflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16192046/901865).