# Open PDF file in Android

Tags: java, android, pdf

Hello I want to open PDF file in Android app, I found this [apv pdf](http://code.google.com/p/apv/) reader in code.google and it is recommended by alot.

I checked the [setup page](http://code.google.com/p/apv/wiki/BuildingLibs#Current_building_method) and it is assume you are using Linux and I am Windows user + I am not good in configure libraries.

Can you show me how to configure it in windows and integrate in my app? 
OR 
if there is good tutorial for that?

Comment: This shows how to create an Intent to open a PDF file programmatically. It will work with any PDF reader app. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2883355/how-to-render-pdf-in-android

Comment: it is required to open pdf inside app

Comment: I would recommend using a linux distro available. Just install it using v-Box or VMware Player. It is way too easier than using cygwin. I had experienced it before.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The instructions provided work for Windows as well. You need to install [cygwin](http://www.cygwin.com/) and then follow those instructions from a cygwin prompt to build the libraries. It looks like you'll also need to install [Android NDK](http://developer.android.com/sdk/ndk/index.html).

Comment: thanks but how to use this command in windows: ./configure --prefix="/target/dir" --host=arm-linux --disable-shared --enable-static

Comment: In Windows, install cygwin, and you then type that command into a cygwin command window (you don't type it into a windows/dos command window)