# which library to use for displaying PDF file in application?

Tags: android

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to render PDF in Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2883355/how-to-render-pdf-in-android)

My question is just simple.
which of the following library is used for displaying PDF file in android powered devices?

**1.Qoppa**

**2.muPDF**

**3.iText**

**4.pdfBox**

i search a lot on their websites and on stack overflow but i can not get clear idea what actually these libraries do?

I am developing an app that reads eBooks from sdcard as well as from network.So please suggest me, which one should i use?
Thanks..........

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Qoppa is commercial product
2. muPDF is lightweight but GPLed
3. iText is AGPLed, a tailored GPL v3.
4. pdfBox is good but a bit big in size.

Comment: what is GPLed and GPL v3?and Please suggest me which one is better for me?

Comment: It is license of the library. For simple, if you use lib under GPL, your app has to be open source under GPL as well. GPL v3 is even complex, it take away patents beside the source code.

Comment: which one is better to use?I think muPdf is good because it's open source.what would you suggest me?

Comment: I suggest you to try pdfBox, it is an Apache powered project, unless you are going to open source your app.

Comment: is pdfBox allows to display PDF file on android devices?

Answer (score 0):

I came across the same problem as you. I tried all of the above. None really worked for me. After some research I found out almost all phones come stock with Adobe Reader (Or any other pdf reader). So I just went for an Intent that would open the pdf file in an installed pdf reader.

Comment: I know about the intent that would open the pdf file in adobe Reader.I want user be able to view pdf file in my application.That's why i have to choose from above mentioned four libraries.but i don't know which one better.