# Are there any broadcast receivers for my Intent?

Tags: java, android

I have developed application which need to use any PDF-Viewer. How can I programatically check the existence of application which are able to respond to my Intent?

Comment: I would recommend using the solution from [here][1].




  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2883355/how-to-render-pdf-in-android/

Comment: Possible duplicate. Look at this [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/2885744/617996).

Answer (score 0):

[This post](http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2009/01/can-i-use-this-intent.html) in the [Android Developers blog](http://android-developers.blogspot.com/) describes how to test for an Intent receiver without actually trying to send the Intent.

As a teaser, here's the important part of the code.  You should read the blog post for more details and a complete function that you can copy and paste.

```
List<ResolveInfo> list =
        packageManager.queryIntentActivities(intent,
                PackageManager.MATCH_DEFAULT_ONLY);
return list.size() > 0;
```