# how to read pdf (content may b image ) in Android

Tags: android, pdf

I want to read a PDF file in android. I placed my PDF files in the assets folder.

How can i read the PDF file from there?

i try itext and PDFBox but i cant get perfect Result My task is create PDFs reader So help..

Comment: Is it good enough to send an Intent? 

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2883355/how-to-render-pdf-in-android/


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2883355/how-to-render-pdf-in-android/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a famous app known as Adobe Reader whereas similar task can also be performed with Documents to Go app

Both are easily available from android market.

Comment: thank for help finally it's done... i implement this https://code.google.com/p/apv/