# Android: How to open a PDF file at a specific page

Tags: android, pdf-viewer

I have seen code [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2883355/how-to-render-pdf-in-android) which will open a PDF file in a PDF viewer. Is it possible to modify the code to make the PDF viewer open the PDF at a specific page?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No. You cannot control 3rd party application unless it gives this possibility.

Comment: Agreed. The third party app would need to have a proprietary field in the intent filter used to designate this. But it's not in the general standard. You'd have to look for a specific app on their device to open the pdf and open it to the correct page.

Comment: Thanks, Andrejs and Brayden. Are there any PDF Viewer apps that include such an intent? (My app is for my use only, so if there is such a PDF Viewer I could get it.)

Comment: There is a few of open source pdf viewers, like [andpdf](http://sourceforge.net/projects/andpdf/) or [apv](http://code.google.com/p/apv/). You could modify the sources to your needs :)

Comment: That's probably a bit beyond my capabilities! But thanks for the suggestion.

Answer (score 3):

Yes there is a way to open a specific page in a pdf file

- Inside Main Activity

```
     @Override
     public void onClick(View v) {
         Intent intent = new Intent(getActivity(), pdfActivity.class);
         intent.putExtra("pageno", 5); // add this to pass the page number
         startActivity(intent);
     }
 });
```

- Inside Pdf Activity

```
pdfView.fromAsset("SAMPLE_FILE.pdf")
     .defaultPage(getIntent().getIntExtra("pageno",0)) // this is used to scroll to the page required
     .enableAnnotationRendering(true)
     .scrollHandle(new DefaultScrollHandle(this))
     .load();
```

If you don't want it to pass through intent

```
pdfView.fromAsset("SAMPLE_FILE.pdf")
     .defaultPage(65) // Write the number of the page
     .enableAnnotationRendering(true)
     .scrollHandle(new DefaultScrollHandle(this))
     .load();
```

Answer (score 2):

Yes You can open a Specific page in pdf file.

first of all create a global varble like

// give a defualt value

```
                int pageNumber=0;

                 //     secondly create   a button in search dilaoge to find exact page in activty.
                    btn.setOnClickListner(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View view) {
                    int position = 1;
                    String input = String.valueOf(textSearch.getText());
                    if (input != null && !input.equals("")) {
                        position = 



                  Integer.valueOf(String.valueOf(textSearch.getText()));
                    }

                    // assign globar var pageNumber to finding position
                    pageNumber = position-1;
                    textSearch.setText("");
                    alertDialog1.dismiss();
                }
```

// in Third Step just passed the pageNumber in defualt function.

```
       pdfViewr.from("Your uri String ").default(pageNumber).load();
```

Answer (score 1):

for ezpdf reader:
add `intent.putExtra("page", 110);`

But ezpdf is quite old. So I recommend you to checkout my new opensource pdf viewer and annotator project:

https://github.com/KnIfER/PolymPic

```
    Intent it = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW)
        .addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK)
        .putExtra("page", yourPageIndex)
        .setDataAndType(yourUri, "application/pdf");
    startActivity(it);
```

It's based on PDFium, which is fast and can even run pretty well on the android 4.4.

Answer (score 0):

Andrejs has recommended that I should modify an open source pdf viewer app. When I become more confident at Android programming I may attempt that. Meanwhile, I am following a different tack. I am storing images of the individual PDF pages as separate jpg files and using WebView / WebViewClient to display the individual pages. These can be zoomed and panned (as in a PDF Viewer) and it is easy to make my app move to the next or previous page when I touch the screen near the edge of the page.

Answer (score -1):

Open a PDF file to a specific page

To target an HTML link to a specific page in a PDF file, add #page=[page number] to the end of the link's URL.

For example, this HTML tag opens page 4 of a PDF file named myfile.pdf:

```
<A HREF="http://www.example.com/myfile.pdf#page=4">
```

Comment: This may be correct for different context but the question is tagged android and pdf-viewer so this answer is irrelevant and not helpful.