# How to open secific range of pages in pdf instead of whole pdf

Tags: java, android, pdf

How to modify the following code to open specific range of pages within the pdf for example from page 5 to 30 instead of opening the whole pdf.
Thanks in advance

```
 IOExcept {touch = new
ZoomableImageView(Part1Activity.this);
linear1.addView(touch);
File file = new File(getCacheDir(), "quran_01.pdf"); if (!file.exists()) { try { InputStream asset = getAssets().open("quran_01.pdf"); FileOutputStream output = null; output = new FileOutputStream(file); final byte[] buffer = new byte[1024]; int size; while ((size = asset.read(buffer)) != -1) { output.write(buffer, 0, size); } asset.close(); output.close(); } catch (IOException e) { e.printStackTrace(); } }
try {
renderer = new android.graphics.pdf.PdfRenderer(new ParcelFileDescriptor(ParcelFileDescriptor.open(new java.io.File(file.getAbsolutePath()), ParcelFileDescriptor.MODE_READ_ONLY)));
android.graphics.pdf.PdfRenderer.Page page = renderer.openPage((int)_position);

Bitmap mBitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap((int)getDip(page.getWidth()), (int)getDip(page.getHeight()), Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);

page.render(mBitmap, null, null, android.graphics.pdf.PdfRenderer.Page.RENDER_MODE_FOR_DISPLAY);

touch.setImageBitmap(mBitmap);

page.close();
} catch (Exception e){
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't modify a third party tool, where the option to change the site range programmatically isn't given.
Thus, you can't use external Viewer without Endpoints to handle.

I recommend to watch for app internal PDF Viewer/Tools that you can modify by code.

Take a look at this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10823193/android-how-to-open-a-pdf-file-at-a-specific-page), it can help you to work around or use the mentioned open source tools. Cheers!