# open a .pdf Document in Adobe Reader from App

Tags: android, pdf

The title says exactly what i want to do.

My App downloads a pdf to eg. /mnt/sdcard/docs/myfile.pdf

I want to Start adobe reader and display this pdf.

I tried many variations of

```
Intent intent = new Intent();                 
intent.setPackage("com.adobe.reader");    
intent.setDataAndType(Uri.parse("/mnt/sdcard/docs/myfile.pdf"), "application/pdf");  
startActivity(intent);
```

The Reader pops up, but says "Could not open File". If i then in the reader that just oppped up, browse to my document and open it, it works. What is this error about and how can my task be done?

Edit: Thanks to KPBirds Link it works now.

i just altered
Uri.parse(path)
to
Uri.fromFile(new File(path))

Comment: look at this

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2883355/how-to-render-pdf-in-android/