# Android - configure app using webview to automatically launch PDF reader when a PDF is downloaded openned

Tags: android, pdf, webview, android-webview

An APP is using webview to display a site as if it were an app. I want to make that APP open the reader when a PDF is downloaded. Is this possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using a Webview then one way you could handle the PDF is to bind an object that extends [`WebViewClient`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebViewClient.html) to your `WebView` using the `setWebViewClientMethod`. The object that extends the `WebViewClient` will need to override the [`onLoadResource`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebViewClient.html#onLoadResource%28android.webkit.WebView,%20java.lang.String%29) method.

Inside this method then check your URL for the pdf extension, or for some other attribute of the URL that indicates a PDF, and fire off a new view intent using the PDF URL. This should either offer to open a PDF in an appropriate app. If you want to have a more paranoid fallback you could use Google's PDF renderer by prefixing your URL with `http://docs.google.com/viewer?url=` then URL encoding the original URL to be opened, for example http://research.google.com/archive/bigtable-osdi06.pdf becomes http://docs.google.com/viewer?url=http%3A%2F%2Fresearch.google.com%2Farchive%2Fbigtable-osdi06.pdf.

Answer (score 0):

Check the content-type of the response and then show the PDF content when appropriate. Have you looked at this post ? [How to render PDF in Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2883355/how-to-render-pdf-in-android/) It outlines a couple of approaches to open a PDF

Comment: No, I mean. My user will be browsing a site inside a webview. He can randomly decide to download a PDF. When he does it, I want that PDF to be openned. How?