# Viewing PDF from URL using Adobe in Android

Tags: android, url, pdf

I'm just learning Android code and I've come upon a problem which I hope you can all help.
I want to display a PDF file from a URL from my application, I've got the PDF to display using a webView method however with having Adobe Reader and Polaris Office installed on my phone I was just wondering if I can load the URL and implement the PDF to be displayed using installed software?
My webView code is as follows:

```
WebView web = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webView);
web.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
String pdf = "http://www.example-site.co.uk/pdf";
web.loadUrl("http://docs.google.com/gview?embedded=true&url=" + pdf);
```

I have searched several posts on here to no avail so any help will be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Searching for "pdf view intent" reveals stuff like that: [How to render PDF in Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2883355/how-to-render-pdf-in-android/)

If that doesn't help, you should try to implement a IntentChooser or directly ask the devs of your two apps on which intent they are listening.

Comment: Oh fantastic! I must've missed that question when searching. Thanks!