# search if is a pdf reader app installed - Android

Tags: android, search, mime

could you help me? I want when enter a specific activity (suppose test device) check if there is any application to read pdfs, if not, display a toast saying that the app is not installed, I neeed to use the mime "application/pdf" right? Thanks for ur Help! and sorry for the bad english

Comment: I think this will help you: [java - How to render PDF in Android](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2883355/how-to-render-pdf-in-android/)

Comment: Thanks this help me when I want to open a pdf, but I want to have a notification if is any pdf reader app installed

Answer (score 0):

Step #1: Create an `Intent` for the operation you wish to perform (e.g., `ACTION_VIEW` for a MIME type of `application/pdf` for a specific `Uri`)

Step #2: Use `PackageManager` and `queryIntentActivities()` or `resolveActivity()` to find out what is installed that can handle this request.